# BottomSheet Fragment Scroll behaviour issue in NestedScrollview present in Bottom sheet layout

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, bottom-sheet, android-nestedscrollview, android-bottom-nav-view

my Scenario is on button click i need to open a bottomsheet which is half expanded and when we drag up it should behave like collasping toolbar.

Here Appbar behaviour is in sync with bottomsheet but somehow NestedScrollview behaviour is only sync with Collasping toolbar not with Bottomsheet behaviour.

When i scroll on NestedScrollview It is just expanding and collasping the Toolbar but not BottomSheet.

below is bottomsheet layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="@dimen/design_appbar_elevation"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"

    app:behavior_hideable="true"

    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"

        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="300dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="222dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[Github link for source code](https://github.com/Feroz-Istar/MyApplication.git)

Below is MainActivity code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
    @BindView(R.id.mine)
    ConstraintLayout mine;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

        View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                switch (newState) {
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "State Collapsed");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                        Log.d(TAG, "State Dragging");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "State Expanded");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                        Log.d(TAG, "State Hidden");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                        Log.d(TAG, "State Settling");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            }
        });

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.click)
    public void click() {
        BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment();
        bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
    }
}
```

below is MainActivity layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/mine"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/click"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>    <!-- Bottom Sheet Dialog Content @set app:layout_behavior = "android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior" -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Below is CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment :

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment  extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    private TextView mOffsetText;
    private TextView mStateText;
    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            setStateText(newState);
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                dismiss();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            setOffsetText(slideOffset);
        }
    };


    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View contentView, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(contentView, savedInstanceState);


//
//        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
//        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.bottomsheetcontent, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
        if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
            ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        }

    }


    private void setOffsetText(final float slideOffset) {

    }

    private void setStateText(int newState) {
    }
}
```

[image: Bootomsheet Scroll behaviour issue in NestedScrollview]

Comment: Could you articulate a bit more clearly what's your goal? What I understood so far is that you want to collapse the dialog when you scroll on the other bottom sheet...

Comment: Refer this: [Handling Scrolls with CoordinatorLayout](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)